# How to make an analogue of Array.isArray() for Map in JS?

Tags: javascript, prototype, proto

I'm researching prototypes in JS.

1. Please tell me how to add the **Map.isMap(*object*)** function to the Map prototype.

I was able to make *object*.isMap() by code:

```
Map.prototype.isMap = function() {
  return this.__proto__.toString().toLowerCase().includes("map");
}
```

2. I know editing prototype chain is a bad practice in JS. What is the best way to create such function?

Comment: Just create a standalone function? `function isMap(value) { return value instanceof Map; }`. Why does it need to be a property of any object?

Comment: hah, OK, thanks

Comment: @FelixKling `Array.isArray` was added precisely because `instanceof` is not enough! Your solution doesn't return `true` for `Map` objects that originate in different contexts and for `Map` objects that have don't have `Map.prototype` in their prototype chains.

Comment: @Melab: My main point was that it's enough to create a standalone function. The implementation can be adjusted as needed. Without any more details I just provided an example of the simplest solution. If you consider an object that adheres to the `Map` API (`get`, `set`, `delete`, etc) then such a function can test for the existence of such methods.